# image:hover to full opacity, but only inside one div?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a page on my website only for my photographs. I put them inside their own div, like so...

```
<div id="imghover">
        <img src="images/Promo.jpg" height="200px" /><img src="images/Promo2.jpg" height="200px" />
    </div>
```

Untouched, they have an opacity of 0.4, but when you hover, they have an opacity of 1.0. Like so...

```
img {
        opacity: 0.4;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    img:hover { 
        opacity: 1.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    }
```

The problem is... The img for my logo is also responding to the style and I don't want it to. I thought I could write this:

```
img:hover#imghover {
```

but it didn't seem to work. I know it's probably really simple, but I am a beginner. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got close. The problem was the specificity and order of the selectors.

**CSS:**

```
#imghover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#imghover img:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```